# "IN" Predicate in SQL

Tags: sql

If I put in my where clause, something like:

```
select col_1, col_2, col_3
from table_1
where col_1 <> col_2;
```

This would not return values were the value in column 1 is not equal to the value in column 2 for that row.

What I want to do is make sure each value in column 1 does not exist anywhere in column 2. For example, if my table has 100 rows, I want to make sure that no value from row 1, 2, 3, etc appear anywhere in the 100 rows for column 2.

What is the best way to approach this?

What I am thinking about doing is this:

```
with table_2 AS(
select col_1
from table_1
)
select *
from table_1
where col_2 NOT IN 
(select col_1
from table_2);
```

Does this accomplish this?

Edit: I am working with a table where there is a one-to-many relationship. I want to make sure the values on the "one" side are nowhere in the "many" side.

Edit Part Two: I did something like this and didn't have any luck because the values from column 1, still showed up in column_2, or column_3,  or column_4, etc.

```
Select *
from table_1 as one
where NOT EXISTS
((select *
from table_two as two
where two.column_2 = one.column_1)
AND
two.column_three = one.column_1));
```

Comment: Read about NOT EXISTS: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-CA/library/ms188336.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: IN is synonymous to 'one of the values'

Comment: What do you mean "IN is synonymous to one of the values' ? Can you be clearer please?

Comment: Pieter Geerkens: "B. Comparing queries by using EXISTS and IN
The following example compares two queries that are semantically equivalent. The first query uses EXISTS and the second query uses IN." Doesn't this mean you can use EXISTS or IN?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What I want to do is make sure each value in column 1 does not exist anywhere in column 2. For example, if my table has 100 rows, I want to make sure that no [column 1] value from row 1, 2, 3, etc appear anywhere in the 100 rows for column 2.

It sounds like you're trying to verify data, in which case you may be better served by returning rows which **fail** your condition — the column_1 value *does* exist somewhere in column_2 — so you can go back and clean them up or evaluate your system to find out where they came from. This query will do that:

```
select distinct t1.*
from table_1 t1
inner join table_1 t2 on t1.column_1 = t2.column_2
```

---

Based on your comments:

```
select distinct t1.*
from table_1 t1
inner join table_1 t2 on t1.column_1 = t2.column_2 

union

select distinct t1.*
from table_1 t1
inner join table_1 t2 on t1.column_1 = t2.column_3 -- note the different column

union

select distinct t1.*
from table_1 t1
inner join table_1 t2 on t1.column_1 = t2.column_4 

union

select distinct t1.*
from table_1 t1
inner join table_1 t2 on t1.column_1 = t2.column_5
```

If you want a cleaner way to do this, without so many unions, than fix your schema, because this is a weak schema design. A better schema would only have two columns for your key data, and a third column indicating which relationship (column) this record indicates.

Comment: Basically, I have one table and I'm trying to make sure that values in column 1 do not show up anywhere in columns 2, 3, 4, or 5 from the same table.

Comment: That's a **very** different problem from what you described in the question! And it's still not clear! Clearly understanding and communicating requirements is the **core** of what programming is about. Anyway, for each row, are you checking against all columns **and** all rows, or just all of the columns within the same row? If the latter, do you also need to make sure the column 2,3,4 etc are unique?

Comment: I apologize. I am trying to find rows from my table in which columns 2, 3, 4, and 5, do not have ANY value from column 1, regardless of where the value is at in the row number. Does that make sense?

Comment: Thank you for your patience/help :) Let me play around with your edited comment and I will respond in just a few minutes (less than 5).

Comment: I like your edited query :)  Just out of curiosity, and because I am learning, why did you suggest the DISTINCT keyword? Wouldn't UNION take care of duplicate values?

Comment: The UNION takes care of the distinct values across separate queries. The DISTINCT is eliminate duplicate values in the same query, in case a value from column_1 matches a value in column_2 more than once. As a matter of practice, the UNION will still have this effect. But as a matter of pure (meaningless) semantics keeping the DISTINCT is more correct.

Comment: Okay, last question :) So the unions gave me a combined query where column 1 is either in column 2, column 3, or column 4 or column 5. What I want to do now is find all of the records in table 1 where they are not in the combined union columns. So what I am thinking is, select * from table 1 where NOT EXISTS (the combined union queries). Does that sound right?

Comment: If I use NOT Exists, no rows come back. If I use EXISTS, all the rows come back. This confuses me because when I ran the combined query with the unions, only 90,000 rows were returned. What do you think Joel?

Comment: Ah, I needed to use a correlated subquery to make EXISTS work. My problem is now solved. Thank you for your help Joel :)